# 8086 Assembly Arrays with I/O

Tags: assembly

I was wondering if it's possible to redifine the size of an array or simply, create a new one through the Code Segment. Here's what I have so far:

```
.DATA
prompt1 db "Please enter a number which will ressemble the N of the array",13,10,'$'
value db ?

.CODE
DisplayIO proc
lea DX, prompt1
mov AH, 09h
int 21h
mov AH, 08h
int 21h
ret
DisplayIO endP
call DisplayIO
sub AL, 30h
mov value, AH
```

What I'm trying to do, is basically create an array with the size of `value`

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In DOS you can use a system call ([int 21h, ah = 0x48](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-48.html)) to reserve a segment of your selected size (all segments are multiples of 16 bytes). Also remember to [free the block](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-49.html) with int 21h, ah=0x49.

> **INT 21,48 - Allocate Memory**
>       AH = 48h
>       BX = number of memory paragraphs requested

```
on return:
AX = segment address of allocated memory block (MCB + 1para)
   = error code if CF set  (see DOS ERROR CODES)
BX = size in paras of the largest block of memory available
     if CF set, and AX = 08 (Not Enough Mem)
CF = 0 if successful
   = 1 if error


- returns segment address of allocated memory block AX:0000
- each allocation requires a 16 byte overhead for the MCB
- returns maximum block size available if error
```

Or you can statically allocate the maximum length buffer from code/data and build your own malloc.

Answer (score 0):

As **Aki Suihkonen** said, allocating memory is the solution. I developed next example with EMU8086: it asks the user for a number (the array size in bytes), then creates an array of that size. For example, enter 20 for an array of 20 bytes, or enter 40 for an array of 20 words. Here is the code (with lots of comments to help you understand) :

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

msg1      db 'Enter the size in byte of the array: $'
size_str  db 6,?,6 dup(?) ;ARRAY SIZE IN STRING.
size_num  dw ?            ;ARRAY SIZE IN NUMERIC.
array_seg dw ?            ;ARRAY ON ALLOCATED MEMORY.

;-----------------------------------------------------------------

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  mov  dx, offset msg1       ;MESSAGE TO DISPLAY.
  call printf

;CAPTURE NUMBER AS STRING.
  mov  dx, offset size_str   ;BUFFER TO STORE CAPTURED STRING.
  call scanf

;CONVERT CAPTURED NUMBER FROM STRING TO NUMERIC.
  mov  si, offset size_str   ;STRING TO CONVERT.
  call string2number         ;NUMBER RETURNS IN BX.
  mov  size_num, bx          ;PRESERVE RETURNED VALUE.

;ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR THE ARRAY.
  call build_array    

;EXAMPLE : FILL ARRAY WITH 0.
  call zeroes

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO '$' FINISHED STRING.

printf proc
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
printf endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO BUFFER TO STORE STRING.

scanf proc
  mov  ah, 0Ah
  int  21h
  ret
scanf endp    

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER.
;PARAMETER : SI POINTING TO STRING CAPTURED WITH 0AH.
;RETURN    : NUMBER IN BX.

string2number proc
;MAKE SI TO POINT TO THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
  inc  si ;POINTS TO THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
  mov  cl, [ si ] ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.                                         
  mov  ch, 0 ;CLEAR CH, NOW CX==CL.
  add  si, cx ;NOW SI POINTS TO LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
;CONVERT STRING.
  mov  bx, 0
  mov  bp, 1 ;MULTIPLE OF 10 TO MULTIPLY EVERY DIGIT.
repeat:         
;CONVERT CHARACTER.                    
  mov  al, [ si ] ;CHARACTER TO PROCESS.
  sub  al, 48 ;CONVERT ASCII CHARACTER TO DIGIT.
  mov  ah, 0 ;CLEAR AH, NOW AX==AL.
  mul  bp ;AX*BP = DX:AX.
  add  bx, ax ;ADD RESULT TO BX. 
;INCREASE MULTIPLE OF 10 (1, 10, 100...).
  mov  ax, bp
  mov  bp, 10
  mul  bp ;AX*10 = DX:AX.
  mov  bp, ax ;NEW MULTIPLE OF 10.  
;CHECK IF WE HAVE FINISHED.
  dec  si ;NEXT DIGIT TO PROCESS.
  loop repeat ;COUNTER CX-1, IF NOT ZERO, REPEAT.

  ret 
string2number endp

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;TO BUILD THE ARRAY IS NECESSARY TO ALLOCATE MEMORY. MEMORY IS
;ALLOCATED IN BLOCKS OF 16 BYTES CALLED "PARAGRAPHS". IT'S NOT
;POSSIBLE TO ALLOCATE ODD NUMBERS, ONLY MULTIPLES OF 16. FOR
;EXAMPLE, FOR AN ARRAY OF 20 BYTES IT'S NECESSARY TO ALLOCATE TWO
;PARAGRAPHS (12 BYTES WASTED).

build_array proc
;FIND OUT HOW MANY PARAGRAPHS WILL BE NEEDED DIVIDING THE
;REQUESTED MEMORY SIZE BY 16.
  mov  ax, size_num     ;REQUESTED MEMORY.
  mov  bl, 16           ;DIVISOR.
  div  bl               ;AX / 16 : AL=QUOTIENT, AH=REMAINDER.

;IF REMAINDER == 0, SIZE_NUM IS MULTIPLE OF 16, IF REMAINDER != 0,
;ADD ANOTHER PARAGRAPH (SOME BYTES WASTED).
  cmp  ah, 0
  je   is_multiple      ;IF AH == 0 : JUMP.
;IF NO JUMP, REMAINDER != 0.
  inc  al               ;ANOTHER PARAGRAPH WILL BE NEEDED.

is_multiple:

;ALLOCATE THE MEMORY PARAGRAPHS.
  mov  bl, al           ;NUMBER OF PARAGRAPHS.
  mov  bh, 0            ;CLEAR BH TO USE BX.
  call allocate  

  ret
build_array endp

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;ALLOCATES "N" PARAGRAPHS OF MEMORY. ONE PARAGRAPH = 16 BYTES.
;THE RETURNED MEMORY IS A SEGMENT, "ES" CAN BE USED TO POINT TO IT.
;PARAMETER : BX = HOW MANY PARAGRAPHS TO ALLOCATE.
;RETURN    : VARIABLE "ARRAY_SEG" WITH ADDRESS OF ALLOCATED SEGMENT.

allocate proc
  mov  ah, 48h          ;SERVICE TO ALLOCATE MEMORY.
  int  21h              ;RETURNS AX = SEGMENT OF MEMORY ALLOCATED.
  mov  array_seg, ax 
  ret
allocate endp  

;-----------------------------------------------------------------
;FILL ARRAY WITH ZEROES.

zeroes proc
  mov  ax, array_seg    ;REMEMBER : ARRAY IS A SEGMENT,
  mov  es, ax           ;THAT'S WHY "ES" MUST BE USED.

  mov  si, 0            ;SI = INDEX FOR THE ARRAY.
  mov  cx, size_num     ;SIZE IN BYTES OF THE ARRAY.
  mov  dl, 0            ;VALUE TO FILL ARRAY.

filling:
  mov  [ es:si ], dl    ;STORE ZERO IN CURRENT POSITION.
  inc  si               ;MOVE SI TO NEXT POSITION.
  loop filling          ;CX-1. IF CX > 0 : REPEAT.

  ret
zeroes endp

;-----------------------------------------------------------------

end start
```

Some notes :

- The number entered by user must be divided by 16 because memory is allocated in blocks of 16 bytes.
- The array is stored in its own memory segment (not in the data segment), that's why `ES` must be used to access it.
- The number is captured from keyboard as string, then converted to number.