# 8086 Assembly - Input a number greater than 9

Tags: assembly

This is the interrupt I use to input a number, however it does not allow me to input numbers greater than 9:

```
mov AH, 08h
int 21h
```

Is there a different interrupt which will allow me to input a 2-digit number as well?

Comment: Thing is, I intend to use the number later on. I don't want it to be divided into digits and prinited out afterwards.

Comment: Capture the number as string, then convert it to number. To display a number, convert it to string, here are the procs you need = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243848/assembly-x86-date-to-number-breaking-a-string-into-smaller-sections/30244131#30244131 . With this answer you can input bigger numbers.

Comment: And String input is AH = 09h, right?

Comment: 09 is output (printf), 0A is input (scanf).

Comment: A simpler example = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724177/8086-assembly-arrays-with-i-o/30736531#30736531

Answer (score 2):

With `08h` you are requesting a single character input, see documentation e.g. [here](http://80864beginner.com/8086-Interrupt-List/int-21h-Dos-Interrupt.html) or a tutorial [here](http://www.csi.ucd.ie/staff/jcarthy/home/alp/alp2-3.html). Reading two digits will then take two `int 21h`s. Alternatively, you may take a look at using `0ah` [buffered input](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a), but considering it's only two characters:

```
mov ah, 08h
int 21h
mov dl, al
int 21h
; now dl contains the first character, al the second
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to simply insert a 2-digit number with a single action?

Comment: It's not how hardware works. But as Jose points out in his comment, you can write yourself a helper function which wraps multi-character input for you.

Comment: @Steven1903 There's away to read an entire line. There's also away to read a certain number of characters, but when that number of characters is two, you might as well do what Jens suggests.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with mov ah, 01h ??